# How can I check adaptive response buffering is being used by Microsoft Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I'm using Talend's ETL functionality and I want to make sure that sql server access is pulling results through adaptive response buffering. This is a Java based software and I've configured the connection string parameter with

```
responseBuffering=adaptive
```

but I can't observe a difference between memory usage or performance when change responseBuffering to full or change selectMethod to direct etc. (mostly due to my test setup)

Is there a way of checking if adaptive response buffering is used from sql server profiler? It would be great if I could confirm this from the sql server side regardless of the client software accessing sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been doing this (somewhat crudely) as follows:

```
String url = connection.getMetaData().getURL();
boolean isAdaptive = url.contains("responseBuffering=adaptive");
```

This should also work:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
boolean isAdaptive = "adaptive".equals(((SQLServerStatement)statement).getResponseBuffering());
```